# How a symbol is used in type position?

Tags: typescript

I don't understand the following sentence in official document about [Typescript module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

> For this pattern to work, it’s important that the symbol defined via
>   an import is only used in type positions (i.e. never in a position
>   that would be emitted into the JavaScript).

**Question1:**

What is "type position"? How a variable is used in type position? So what is non-type position?

**Question2:**

What is "emmiting into into the Javascript"? Can you please give an example? I failed to instantiate this concept.

Comment: Nice: "I failed to instantiate this concept." I will have to use that myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is a language that compiles into JavaScript and uses type annotations to aid the compiler in doing static analysis for type consistency.

So, conceptually, there are two parts to Typescript code: the type annotations, which are not present in the JavaScript, and the transpiled code, which is present in some form in the transpiled code.

For example, here is a silly Typescript program:

```
interface Foo {
  myNumber: number;
  myString: string;
}

function aFunc(foo: Foo) {
  return foo.myString;
}

let foo: Foo = {
  myNumber: 9,
  myString: 'Hola!'
};
```

And running it through `tsc` gives you this:

```
function aFunc(foo) {
    return foo.myString;
}
var foo = {
    myNumber: 9,
    myString: 'Hola!'
};
console.log(aFunc(foo));
```

You can see that the interface declaration and the remaining type annotations do not exist in the compiled code, whereas the other pieces are largely present as-is.

The portions of the code that are removed are in a *type position* and the remaining code is in *code position*. This answers your first question.

And to explicitly answer your second question, running `tsc` on a *.ts file will emit a *.js file, as in the example above.

Comment: Type position is variable or function declared with a type, e.g. number, string, or customized interface type.

Comment: Then, everything is emitted into javascript. Why it says "never in a position that would be emitted into the JavaScript"?

Comment: Not everything is emitted to Javascript. Anything in type position is not emitted. Only code position is emitted.

Comment: I see. Typed variable is compiled to javascript, not emitted to javascript directly literately.